# SQL count function not working properly in view

Tags: mysql

I've created a view to query on but does not seem to be working properly.
Code:

```
    CREATE VIEW SpeciesTypes AS
    SELECT species.Name, count(animal.animalID) as number_of_animals
    FROM zoo.species, zoo.animal
    WHERE species.speciesID = animal.speciesID
    GROUP by Name
```

This code shows each species name and the number of animals within each species. However, i am trying to write a query in **finding out which species has the most number of animals including the species name**.

The query that i used was:

```
    SELECT name, max(number_of_animals)
    FROM speciestypes;
```

This showed me correct highest number of animals but the species name does not change.. does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the name of the species having the greatest number of animals, using your view you can just use a `WHERE` clause to restrict the result set.

```
SELECT t.name,
       t.number_of_animals
FROM SpeciesTypes t
WHERE t.number_of_animals = (SELECT MAX(number_of_animals) FROM SpeciesTypes)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes that works for the final output but my view would require me listing all species and number of animals for each of them, thus i cannot use this method.

Comment: @DarioOngsono I updated again.  Just query the view and add a `WHERE` condition to restrict to the species with the max number of animals.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works great.